# Accessing an object of type, that is the same as the type returned in PowerShell with Hash

Tags: c#, powershell

PowerShell returns following TypeName.

```
PS C:\Users\Mike> $p = Test-connection -Count 1 -Comp localhost
PS C:\Users\Mike> $p | Get-member

    TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_PingStatus

    Name                           MemberType
    ----                           ----------

    ...

    StatusCode                     Property

    ...

    IPV4Address                    ScriptProperty
```

First thing to do would be adding `System.Management` to references, but this gives me possibility to cast "plain" `ManagementObject` which doesn't have access to members like `IPV4Address` or `StatusCode`.

This probably has something to do with sharp symbol after ManagementObject in PowerShell. What does it mean and how can I access same type in C#.

Comment: `IPV4Address` is a ScriptProperty so it not defined on the underlying object. It has been added by PowerShell for convenience. If you are using C# you may just want to use the `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class.

Answer (score 1):

It means it's a `System.Management.ManagementObject` with WMI class `Win32_PingStatus`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeteazb7(v=vs.110).aspx) for the definition in C#

If you wanted to do it in C#, you can do the following:

```cs
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace MOSearcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ManagementObjectCollection mo = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address = 'localhost'").Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject m in mo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m["Address"]);
                Console.WriteLine(m["StatusCode"]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```